# When I am running my NewRelic plugin, it seems to be calling pollCycle twice in a row.

Tags: newrelic-platform

I have written a NewRelic plugin.  I have been debugging it, and noticed that the pollCycle is being called twice in a row.  Since we are resetting our data after each call, this is causing some very skewed numbers.  Anybody have any idea why this is happening or how I can stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the New Relic Java SDK for plugin development, the `pollCycle()` method is invoked once for each Agent that is added via the `runner.add()` method. The runner will call the `pollCycle()` method once for each component created by these agent factories.

You can verify that this is the case by only adding one of the two factories and seeing that `pollCycle()` is called only once.